# Redis bind CIDR address format

Tags: redis

I have a broadband connection and it changes my ip address pretty frequently but will always be from `xx.yy.0.0` to `xx.yy.255.255`

I want to use a CIDR address format like `xx.yy.0.0/16`

When i configure like this, redis server doesn't start up.

One alternative i have in mind is to allow redis on `0.0.0.0` but allow the port `6379` at the firewall to only `xx.yy.0.0/16`

I will end up doing like this, if redis doesn't support CIDR address binding out of the box.

please suggest.